# Destructor of a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constructor, destructor

I have a pointer to string

```
string* relatori;
```

and in the class constructor

```
Conference() : numMaxRel(10)
{
    relatori = new string[numMaxRel];
}
```

It's a standard array with a pointer on the first element? So inside the destrcutor i have to do the following?

```
Conference::~Conference()
{
    delete rel;
}
```

Comment: You `delete`, what you `new`, and you `delete[]`, what you `new[]`. Mixing those (like you have done here) are undefined behavior (one would need to `delete[] relatori;`).

Comment: Use `std::vector` and stop having to worry about this sort of thing.

Comment: yes,  if you allocate memory with operator "new" in constructor, you need free memory by calling "delete" in destructor. But maybe it is better to use std::vector for you?

Comment: Now try this -- `{Conference c1; Conference c2 = c1;}` -- Even if you used the correct form of `delete[]`, this just leads you into the error shown above (double deletion).  You would have just jumped from the frying pan into the fire.  Just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete rel` cannot free the memory of an array. To do so you have to use `delete[] rel`. However, you should be aware, that you can use containers from the standard library which do the memory management for you, like `std::vector<string>`. This should almost always be the preferred way. This is how your class could look like (note: you do not need a destructor):

```
class Conference
{
public:
    Conference() : numMaxRel(10)
    {
        rel.reserve(numMaxRel);
    }

private:
    size_t numMaxRel;
    std::vector<std::string> rel;
};
```

Also note, that you now have a custom copy-constructor and move-constructor, copy- and move-assignments which out of the box, do what you would expect them to do.

Answer (score 0):

to delete the whole array pointed to since you used [] to allocate

```
  delete []rel;
```

Comment: True, i thought it was not needed the [ ], because it's not an array of pointers.